# How do you create a disperse particle in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-effects

Is this from a plugin for illustrator?

[image: https://www.shutterstock.com/ru/image-vector/cyclists-particle-divergent-composition-vector-illustration-342882749]

Answer (score 0):

You can make a dotted pattern and group it then keeping it selected go to thee drop down menu in 'Brush Definition' at the top of the tool bar and open the menu and select 'New Brush...' and select Scatter Brush. Might take a bit to get it right and you might need to make more than one Brush type.